# small Q on js and sharepoint

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

A simple question on interacting between js and sharepoint

I created a js in the asp page to retrieve the list item from sharepoint, I wrote like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(find, "sp.js"); });
 window.onload = function () {
 find();
}
function loadConstants() {     
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); ;
    this.web = clientContext.get_web();     
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    var list = lists.getByTitle("Weekend's Notes");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    this.items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);     
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}
```

below is the finding method

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            //document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_826af611_885a_4a36_8141_91157fa66535_ctl00_TextArea1").innerHTML = oListItem.get_item('Note');

        }
    }
```

everytime it refreshed the browser, it shows that it **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined**
Can anybody give me a hand? Totally have no ideas about that...

Comment: Which line throws the error??

Comment: Errors come with line numbers. You see, the line number tells us on which line the error occurred, so that we don't have to try to find that spot by force/chance/luck. Anyways, that line number thingy would be kind-of useful here, so if you don't mind checking on which line the error occurred, we'd really appreciate it.  `:P`

Comment: Where does C#, ASP.NET, and jQuery come into play here?

Comment: Hi everyone, I appreciate your quick reply, the thing is, is it the approperiate way for me to import the sp.js? Caz I tested that and the function constants() wasn't even called

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you run the script before your ClientContext is created. See if this helps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245759(v=office.15).aspx